# A Subview in a stackview, uninstalled in size class C:R, moves away from stackview when rotate to C:C size class

Tags: swift, ios9, xcode7, size-classes, uistackview

Using `swift2`, `xcode7` and `iOS9`.

Im pretty new in swift xcode ios developing, but trying to use autolayout and size classes.

I have a horizontal `UIstackview` with 3 subviews created in storyboard for any size class. In the wC: hC (iPhone portrait) size class I have one of the subviews uninstalled. No coding done, just using storyboard.

When running the app on the iPhone, in portrait modes the stackview perfectly shows two subviews as expected. But, when rotating to landscape, the subview which gets installed,  moves out of the stackview and appears in the upper left corner of the screen. In the portrait mode the subview was deleted form the stackview's arrangedviews and subviews lists, but in landscape mode the subview was added to the subviews list, but NOT to the arrangedviews list. Which make the subview go to the upper left corner of the screen.

Does anyone know if this is a bug or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Hi marten, when you say installed and uninstalled, what do you mean? Did you delete one of the subviews? Also wC:hC is not portrait, it's landscape.  And how are you "installing" a subview in storyboard, to my knowledge to add a subview to a stackview when the orientation changes you must do this in code.  Let me know the answers and I'll help you answer your question.

Comment: Are you still working on this?